Analyzing the Kelvin Statement
We know that the Kelvin Postulate is:

No possible process whose only final result is to transform into work, heat extracted from a source at a constant temperature throughout.

The question then is:
If heat is extracted from a source which is not at a constant temperature throughout, can we device a transformation whose only final result is to transform into work, heat extracted from the source.
Question is inspired by the fact that an isothermal expansion of ideal gas can transform into work heat absorbed from a source at a constant temperature throughout.

If you have something that is not a constant temperature throughout, then you can find a region of excess hotness and a region of excess coldness, and use that temperature difference to run a Carnot engine. An isothermal expansion of ideal can cannot transform heat absorbed into work, because you need to consider how to return the ideal gas to its initial volume.

The statement should not be taken literally, because even when there are two reservoirs of two different temperatures, and work can be extracted via heat engine, this still does not happen in a way whose only final result is transformation into work, because the other result is, always, change of energy of the reservoirs and the associated change of their state(contraction, expansion, possibly change of temperature).

@naturallyinconsistent Thank you Sir!  However, I was referring to a case where the distribution of heat throughout the source is constant. However, the temperature throughout the entire process is not constant. I.e, the temperature source is not a "reservoir", it's temperature changes

The key point to understand Kelvin's statement of the second law of Thermodynamics is in the words whose only final result. This implies that, apart from the transformation of heat into work, nothing else has changed between the initial and final state.
For this reason, isothermal expansion is not a counterexample. Although the expansion work is done in the presence of a source at a constant temperature, the final state (expanded gas) is clearly different from the initial state.

Yes sir! Isothermal expansion of ideal gas is not a counterexample. It's just that I was playing around with all possible clauses of Kelvin Statement.

The idea I was trying to understand was the importance of each clause. Just like in the isothermal expansion case we were able to convert all heat into work, but there was a change of state. Similarly, I was thinking what process could help me transform into work, all heat absorbed(not at constant temp. throughout) without change of state


We know that the Kelvin Postulate is:
No possible process whose only final result is to transform into work,
heat extracted from a source at a constant temperature throughout.

In my opinion, that's a poor way of describing the postulate. The term "final result" can be ambiguous. The better description is
No heat engine can operate in a cycle while exchanging heat with a single heat reservoir.
By stating it in terms of a cycle rather than a process it is clear that the "final result" means all the system properties must return to their original state.

The question then is:
If heat is extracted from a source which is not at a constant
temperature throughout, can we device a transformation whose only
final result is to transform into work, heat extracted from the
source.

A heat source and heat sink are required by the second law. These  can be the higher and lower temperature regions of your source where the temperatures are not constant throughout. However, the maximum thermal efficiency occurs if the heat transfers are reversible and if the temperatures in those regions do not change during the heat transfers, making the regions heat reservoirs locally. That's the Carnot cycle efficiency.
Hope this helps.
